# How to solve $X'X=A$

Tags: matrices

I am doing some statistical calculations.

Suppose I know $X'X=\begin{pmatrix}
 50& 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0& 60 &0  & 0\\ 
 0&  0&  80& 20\\ 
 0& 0 &20  & 80
\end{pmatrix}$

$X'$ is the transpose of $X$ here.

My question is: Can I solve $X$ from this equation? or some function forms of $X$?

The Lyapunov Equation seems not work here. Matlab, R, c++ or any numberic soltion will be appreciated too.

Thanks.

Comment: There is not a unique solution here. For instance, let $O$ be some orthogonal matrix with the same dimension as the number of rows of $X$ and let $Z = OX.$ Then $Z'Z = X'O'OX = X'X.$

Comment: Thanks, we don't know $X$ here, therefore, $Z$ cannot be decided either here.  I guess there may have a lot of solutions, then can we get one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, there is no unique solution.

There is a name to such decomposition, cholesky decomposition.

One possible solution can be obtained by eigenvalue decomposition. where $A$ is your symmetric matrix.

$$A=UDU^T=UD^\frac12D^\frac12U^T=(D^\frac12U)^T(D^\frac12U)$$

where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal.  Then you can choose $X$ to be $D^\frac12U$ to be a feasible solution.

You might also like to check out the function chol in R or Matlab.

Comment: Thanks, I will look this solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there more stricted solution that $U$  is a real matrix and not necessarily square?

Comment: Well, you can also patch zero. $\begin{bmatrix} U & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} D & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} U^T \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}=UDU^T$

Comment: That's right, then how to restrict U to real numbers only?

Comment: $U$ consists of orthonormal eigenvectors. They are real numbers.

Comment: Ok, that will change to spectral decomposition?

Comment: $UDU^T$ is indeed just spectral decomposition.